# How to grab string(s) before the second " - "?

Tags: javascript, jquery

var string = "bs-00-xyz";

As soon as the second dash has detected, I want to grab whatever before that second dash, which is **bs-00** in this case.

I am not sure what is the most efficient way to do that, and here is what I come up with.

`JSFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/tm3pr1h9/`

HTML

```
<input id="searchbox" placeholder="Enter SKU or name to check availability " type="text" />
```

JS

```
$("#searchbox").keyup(function() {

        var query = this.value;
        var count = (query.match(/-/g) || []).length;
        if( count == 2 ){

            var results = query.split('-');
            var new_results = results.join('-')
            alert( "Value before the seond - is : " + new_results );
        }


});
```

Comment: With a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) - try something, if it doesn't work report back. (Well, a split and/or index and substring would work as well..)

Comment: Always post your code in your question when linking to jsFiddle. You saw the warning, yet you chose to try and sidestep it by highlighting a link as code.

Comment: Please see my JSFiddle,  I ave a hard time puting it in my post - sorry guys.

Comment: Not best solution but you can use `string.substr(0, string.lastIndexOf('-'))`

Comment: get the indexOf of second dash and get the substring from 0th position to indexOf(second dash) +1

Comment: as variant with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): `var results = query.split('-').slice(0,2).join('-');` if you sure that in string one or more _'-'_

Comment: Is it possible that string doesn't contain 2 dashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there are more than two dashes in your string...

```
var myString = string.substr(0, string.indexOf('-', string.indexOf('-') + 1));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it without regex with this

```
myString.split('-').splice(0, 2).join('-');
```

Comment: you should probably check array length. This will work for string 'foo' which has no dashes at all

Comment: @Glen Swift: added a comment asking is it's possible to have strings with less than 2 dashes and what to do in that case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression match:

```
var string = "bs-00-xyz";
newstring = string.match(/([^-]+-[^-]+)-/i);

// newstring = "bs-00"
```

This will work for strings with more than two dashes as well.

Example:

```
var string = "bs-00-xyz-asdf-asd";
```

Comment: I would use `*` instead of `+`, but I guess the spec is ambiguous.  Does `/i` actually do anything here?

Comment: @Samuel Edwin Ward: You're right.  i doesn't really do anything here.  The + makes sure there is at least one non dash character.  * doesn't need to match anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think splitting on character is a fine approach, but just for variety's sake...you could use a regular expression.

```
var match = yourString.match(/^([^\-]*\-[^\-]*)\-/);
```

That expression would return the string you're looking for as `match[1]` (or null if no such string could be found).

Comment: If the string has three dashes, this will give you the part before the third dash rather than the second.

Answer (score 0):

you need use `lastIndexOf` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm3pr1h9/1/), check this example

link update...